# Where's my RAM disk being stored?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap, ramdisk, tmpfs

I'm running an Ubuntu VM under Windows 7, within the VM I've allocated a 5GB RAM disk using `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=5G tmpfs /mnt/gitRAM` and then copied files into it. When I then look at conky which shows my RAM, Swap and disk usage I see what's in this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the contents of `/mnt/gitRAM` are about 2.4GiB but my combined RAM and swap usage is only showing as 1531MiB, meaning that 926.6MiB of stuff isn't accounted for, not including actual system RAM usage.

Is the contents of tmpfs not included in RAM usage? Is there any way of seeing if my tmpfs has things stored in RAM or Swap?

Answer (score -1):

tmpfs stores things in RAM up to a maximum of 5G in your case.
Something is probably not displayed correctly.

Comment: The question was "Is the contents of tmpfs not included in RAM usage?". That's what I answered.